# My button loads a page underneath the current page

Tags: html, angular

I have created a button in a html file inside an Angular component. When I click on the button it loads the page underneath the current page and making a single long page, instead of showing a new page. How do I solve this?

```
<button type="button" class="btn m-1 btn btn-success w-100" (click)="btnClick();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Open page</button>
```

```
 btnClick= function () {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/testcomponent');
  };
```

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm col-md-4">

      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center">OPTIONS</h5>
          <p class="card-text">

            <button type="button" class="btn m-1 btn btn-success w-100" (click)="btnClick();"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Open page</button>



          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { TestComponent} from './testcomponent/testcomponent.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'testcomponent', component: TestComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]


})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have you tried using ```href``` or ```[routerLink]```

Comment: can you post your html file .I wonder if you have any reference to <testcomponent></testcomponent> on the html file from where you are clicking the button

Comment: Can you specify what you mean? Or give an example.

Comment: are you using custom module or generic module? Please post your app.module content(routes specially)

Comment: my guess is in your html file you have <testcomponent></testcomponent>.Something like this:<div class="myclass"></div><button (click)=""></button><testcomponent></testcomponent>

Comment: I added the app.module content. I specified the path and the component here

Comment: can  you try this.router.navigate(['/testcomponent']).The documentation on navigateByUrl states following:

   * If the given URL begins with a `/`, router will navigate absolutely.
   * If the given URL does not begin with `/`, the router will navigate relative to this component.

Comment: Have you added the <router-outlet></router-outlet> to the parent of testcomponent?

Comment: Yes I did put it there

Answer (score 0):

`<a [routerLink]="['/testcomponent']">Open page</a>` or 
`<a href="/testcomponent">Open page</a>`
 for more information 
please refer this https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Unfortunately It did not work. It gave the same results

Comment: Does your application have a router-outlet? And how is your routing configured? Is it at all?